# GPG keys not working when using su - <user>

Tags: linux, kde, gnupg

I've two accounts on my home machine, one work, one general. Occassionally I want to access my pass password database from my general account whilst logged in as my work user. Problem is I get the following error;

gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

This is using Arch Linux and KDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the password will be entered through either the tty or an X window, and both are owned by the original user. I found people suggesting to use `screen` to start a new tty, but even that didn't work. I got `/run/screen/.... No such file or directory"

The answer was:

```
su - user
script /dev/null
screen
```

From [here](https://serverfault.com/a/782338/184743), which credits [this](https://dbadump.blogspot.com/2009/04/start-screen-after-sudo-su-to-another.html) as the original source.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because the GPG key belongs to the user and not to root.

In the post
[user GPG key not able to be used by SUDO](https://serverfault.com/questions/110314/user-gpg-key-not-able-to-be-used-by-sudo)
the accepted answer by the poster was:

> Solution: Added the following to the bash script:
>
> ```
> HOME=/home/user/
> ```

Another solution was to add the parameter
`--gpg-options "--homedir=/home/username/.gnupg"`.

Still another solution was to use the `--preserve-env` option of sudo,
for GPG in the sudo session to be able to find the gpg-agent running
in the use session, like this:

```
sudo --preserve-env command
```

Comment: I'm not using sudo, I'm using su to change to another user, and the "su -" form of the command should set all of the appropriate env variables. It does for HOME certainly

Comment: `su` sets the environment variables HOME and SHELL, plus USER and LOGNAME if the target user is not root. From my answer, you may still use `--gpg-options` with `--homedir` to access your original user's GPG keys.

Comment: I afraid I don't see anyway that this can work